# Is it possible to create dynamic content on file read operation?

Tags: linux, files, pipe

Is it possible to generate file content based on file name?

I need a lot of similar `.conf` files with content depending on file name only.

Can I create some "dynamic" file and generate a bunch of symlinks pointing to this file?

Maybe fifo is a solution, but I can't get the file name in generating script:

```
zsh$ mkfifo ./dynamic.conf
zsh$ ln -s ./dynamic.conf ./case1.conf
zsh$ echo $0  > ./dynamic.conf & 
zsh$ cat ./case1.conf
```

I have `zsh` (I need `case1.conf`).

Comment: So you have an application/program that reads all these `.conf` files and you want to consolidate them all into one file which dynamically spits out the appropriate information for the program's chosen file name?  If so, respond and I'll give you a rather interesting answer. If not, please clarify the question.

Comment: yes, you are correct. looking forward for answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Totally different approach** because I just know your eyes are rolling at that last answer.

In this one, you're going to rely on `inotify` which means it's really Linux-specific. You're going to turn the problem on its head -- the individual configuration files will still be there, but you will re-generate them automagically *each time there is a change to the master*.

You have your "master" configuration file, say `master.conf`, that contains all your sections, sub-sections, etc. You set up your script with `inotify` so that when that script is changed, it will re-write all those files. (To avoid a race condition, you might have to do some extra tricks, like storing the files in a sub-directory, and swapping directories to perform your "commit".)

From https://stackoverflow.com/q/5316178/3849157 we get a basic perl script:

```
my $inotify = Linux::Inotify2->new;
$inotify->watch("/etc/master.conf", IN_MODIFY);
while () {
  my @events = $inotify->read;
  unless (@events > 0){
    print "read error: $!";
    last ;
  }

  foreach my $event (@events) {
    next unless $event->IN_MODIFY;
    # 1. TODO: RE-READ IN THE CONFIG FILE
    # (example)
    $config_hash = &parse_master_file;

    # 2. TODO: RE-GENERATE YOUR CONFIG FILES
    # (example)
    for $section qw( section1 section2 misc ) {
        open(S,"> /etc/${section}.conf")
        print S &dump_config($config_hash,$section)
        close(S)
    }
  }
}
```

Doing the `parse_master_file` and `dump_config` will be up to you. Also, there probably should be a call to sleep in the main loop or your CPU will catch on fire.

Comment: thanks, for both solutions. I need some time to understand first one. Yes it looks complicated

Comment: Ignore the first one, really. It's "cool" in a "I'm going to jump past a  speeding-train" kind of way.

Comment: ok, thanks. And what about /proc files? Is it definitely deadlock, or should i dig in this direction also?

Comment: I think inotify works only on non-virtual filesystems. I'm pretty sure it's not something you can do with /proc.

Comment: A think fuse-based solution is best option. http://fuse.sourceforge.net/helloworld.html

Comment: That's quite brilliant.  I managed to use fuse in an esoteric way and deadlock my entire system.  But in retrospect, I was doing something silly.

Answer (score 1):

You have an application/program that reads all these `.conf` files and you want to consolidate them all into one file which dynamically spits out the appropriate information for the program's chosen file name. The problem with the pipe-based solution is that the program feeding the pipe cannot detect the file that the consumer has opened or wants to read. So you need another method.

A little-known solution to a frustrating problem from another domain: when building rpms, we need to short-cut the rpmbuild process to fix some minor problem with the final packaging step. The `spec` file has several "sections" pertinent to the RPM we are building... prepare, build, files. When our program builds but there's some error in the files section, we want rpmbuild to skip the recompilation. But it won't do that.... by design.

Some guy figure out that you can use `LD_PRELOAD` to load a specially-designed `so`/dll file which traps the `open` call. If the `open` call is to a spec file, it will provide null entries for all but the `files` section, so that when `rpmbuild` is reading the file, it's actually reading what this DLL is telling it is there.

I used it for many weeks, but at some point, I wiped the VM, removing that program from existence and have since been unable to find it. :( A program called `mock` does this now, but I have no idea if it does it the same way or uses another approach.

But that's the idea. You need to find create a DLL which can load via LD_PRELOAD and override the `open` call for that program, but pass along the call (to the real one) for files you are not interested in. For those you are interested in, it feeds the data found and consolidated by your main file.

Sound complicated? Yeah a little.On the bright side, you'll then have the tools to create some really nasty root-kits and trojans.

To verify this might work, run the program using `ltrace -e open <program>` like this:

```
ltrace -e open /usr/bin/tail /etc/fstab
```

You'll see this output (similar)...

```
(0, 0, 0, 0x7f1c32ade000, 88)                             = 0x3055621160
open("/etc/fstab", 0, 00)                             = 4
```

As long as your program is using glibc to open these files (and not, say a direct system call), you'll see it in the output above, and you're in business.

The next step: some guy [describes in detail](https://scaryreasoner.wordpress.com/2007/11/17/using-ld_preload-libraries-and-glibc-backtrace-function-for-debugging/) how to override the `ioctl` call. That will put you on the right track. [A very nice tutorial here.](http://samanbarghi.com/blog/2014/09/05/how-to-wrap-a-system-call-libc-function-in-linux/)

Comment: As an alternate solution, you could use the same technique to override the open call in the following way: When the first configuration file is opened, you block, then spawn another process which splits your consolidated file and writes all the little ones, and when it has completed, you call the standard open() call as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Presented solutions are too crazy for production use.

From the fact that you seem fine with inotify approach (files are explicitly regenerated after master conf modification) it follows that you can just have a simple script which regenerates all your junk. There, inotify avoided with no loss of functionality. The upside is you have fewer things to debug and don't have to babysit the process in the background.

For lulz, it should be noted that it the functionality in question could be achieved, but I fail to see any reason to do it. Here it goes: a special filesystem (e.g. fuse-based) et voila - open, read etc. routines issued by anyone dealing with these files end up calling your code, so you can feed back any content you want. But again, why on earth would you do that.

Comment: yes, thanks. i think fuse is best solution. In my case I need

Comment: NO. You very likely don't want any of this stuff. You only want to generate files after you modify your template and for that you don't need any magic. If you needed the magic, you would know how to do it yourself.

Comment: yes, thanks. i think fuse is best solution. For example I need dhcpd config file as follows

    host 10-10-12-101 {
        hardware ethernet AA:10:10:12:01:01;
        fixed-address 10.10.12.101;
        }
    host 10-10-12-102 {
        hardware ethernet AA:10:10:12:01:02;
        fixed-address 10.10.12.102;
        }
   ... and so on ...

so, why i should regenerate it each time when something have changed. Pointing file to script which generate it is relief